# Open Whatsapp on a particular number in swift

Tags: ios, whatsapp

I am trying to open a particular contact chat in whatsapp but not getting any solution. Please help i am totally stuck. I have tried this:

```
let whatsAppURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?abid=\(primary)&;text=lOL;")!
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(whatsAppURL){
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(whatsAppURL)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [whatsapp forum link](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013), there is no way you can send message to specific user, this is not available within whatsapp URL scheme.

You just set predefined message and then with URL scheme you are able to open whatsapp recent controller.

Comment: Sheereen S's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45351187/1898973) is correct. Sending a Whatsapp to a particular phone number, even if it is not a contact in the address book, is completely possible.

Answer (score 54):

Its possible You can send messages to Specfic user.

**Direct app chat url open**

```
let urlWhats = "whatsapp://send?phone=+919789384445&abid=12354&text=Hello"
    if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
        if let whatsappURL = URL(string: urlString) {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL!) {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsappURL!)
            } else {
                print("Install Whatsapp")
            }
        }
    }
```

> Note:Country code (Ex:+91) is mandatory to open mobile number Chat

**WebUrl Link open Chat**

```
 let whatsappURL = URL(string: "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=9512347895&text=Invitation")
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

Check below link,

https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/26000030

Note: Add url scheme in info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
 </array>
```

Comment: if this answer not works, just try without +, it should work, i just tried it works

Answer (score 31):

**For swift 4.2 / Swift 5**

```
func openWhatsapp(){
    let urlWhats = "whatsapp://send?phone=(mobile number with country code)"
    if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed){
        if let whatsappURL = URL(string: urlString) {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL){
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                } else {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsappURL)
                }
            }
            else {
                print("Install Whatsapp")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**For Swift 2.0**

```
let urlWhats = "whatsapp://send?phone=(mobile number with country code)"
        if let urlString = urlWhats.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()){
            if let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlString) {
                if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(whatsappURL){
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(whatsappURL)
                }
                else {
                    print("Install Whatsapp")
                }
            }
        }
```

**Note: Add url scheme in info.plist**

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
 </array>
```

Comment: This solution worked but I would like to know why adding url scheme, because the solution still works without url scheme in info.plist

Answer (score 5):

This worked neatly for me

```
    if let url = URL(string: "https://wa.me/91xxxxxxxxxx?text=Hello"),
            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Add attributes to the `Info.plist` source code file like this:

   ```
   <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
   <array>
       <string>whatsapp</string>
   </array>
   ```
2. Use the following function on custom click in your app:

   ```
   func openWhatsapp(){
       let urlWhats = "https://wa.me/numberWithCountryCode"
       if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed){
           if let whatsappURL = URL(string: urlString) {
               if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL){
                   if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                       UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                   } else {
                       UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsappURL)
                   }
               } else {
                   Alert(withMessage: "You do not have WhatsApp installed! \nPlease install first.").show(andCloseAfter: 2.0)
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This issue really helpful

just put people number without "+"
example: 60161234567

Answer (score -3):

This is not possible you can just open WhatsApp  with URL scheme.

Comment: This is possible we can open Whatsapp contact chat using above code.